# How to install Android application as system app

Tags: sleep, signature, power-management, locks, wakeup

I am trying to learn how to install any application as system app.

Basically i am trying to use goToSleep and WakeUp function calls in android. I understand that to use these call in your application , application must be installed as system application.

Tried building application with permissions in Manifist.xml as given below

```
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"
```

goToSleep call was used as discribed below

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.goToSleep(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 10);
```

After successfully building the application the application was loaded into /system/app directory of android filesystem using following commands

adb remount ;
adb push <*.apk> /system/app/

Running the application with above changes resulted in Error
**"Neither user 10050 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER."**

I also read that application must be signed as system app for this to successfully work
**i have the copy of android kernel source that i built, Using this how do i sign the current application as system application and successfully test the goToSleep functionality**

Thanks,
-SP-

Answer (score 0):

You would need to root the android device and place the APK inside the system/app directory. I believe that's the only way around to convert any custom application to system app.